# Solving slow reading via chunking

Tags: javascript

I have an array of `File`'s and I need to store their content in Objects of the form `{name:...,content:...}` where content is a `Blob|ArrayBuffer`.

Filling the `content` field requires to read the `File`, but doing so with stuff 3MB worth or more is incredibly expensive in terms of performance (to the point the entire application crashes).

At the moment I'm using this snippet

```
var results = []

[File, File, File, ...].forEach(function (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = function() {
        results.push({name: file.name, content: reader.result})
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
})
```

For some vague reasons I thought to switch to a chunked solution via

```
var results = []

// Chunksize is 1M
var chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1

var fileSize = file.size

// Starting with an empty Blob
var blob = new Blob()

for (var i = 0; i < fileSize; i += chunkSize) {
    (function (f, start) {
        var reader = new FileReader()

        // Slicing file in chunks
        var tmpBlob = f.slice(start, start +chunkSize)

        reader.onload = function() {
            // Merging the old chunks with the just read one
            blob = new Blob([blob, reader.result])

            // If dealing with the last chunk, push
            // the result into the results array
            if (start +chunkSize >= fileSize) {
                results.push({
                    name: file.name,
                    content: blob
                })
            }
        }

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(tmpBlob)
    })(file, i)
}
```